# JList override cell's toString for correct display

Tags: java, overriding, jlist, point, defaultlistmodel

Good day everyone!
I have few question: how i can override my JList's method, i have some array of Point, and they like walk between server and client side, so i can't just override Point's toString(). And my logic tell me, that i can do it in my JList or DefaultListModel, but i can't find information (probably i don't know how google that). So maybe anybody know how do it?

P.s. sorry for my English and grammar;

```
public class PointsList extends JPanel {
    private Extra extra;
    private JList<Point> pointsList;
    private DefaultListModel<Point> listModel;

    public PointsList(Extra extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
        setBackground(Settings.pointListBackround);
        listModel = new DefaultListModel<Point>();
        pointsList = new JList<Point>(
               //Which method i must override, to change cell toString
        };
        pointsList.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(getSelectionListAction());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(pointsList);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
    }

    private ListSelectionListener getSelectionListAction() {
        return new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    extra.setSelectedPoint(pointsList.getSelectedValue());
                    extra.repaintCanvas();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void updateList() {
        listModel.removeAllElements();
        for (Map.Entry<Point, Boolean> currentPoint : extra.getPoints().entrySet()) {
            listModel.addElement(currentPoint.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

My answer: (I don't want create new class, cos' this is few code)

```
public class PointsList extends JPanel {
    private Extra extra;
    private JList<Point> pointsList;
    private DefaultListModel<Point> listModel;

    public PointsList(Extra extra) {
        this.extra = extra;
        setBackground(Settings.pointListBackround);
        listModel = new DefaultListModel<Point>();
        pointsList = new JList<Point>(listModel);
        pointsList.setCellRenderer(getRender());
        pointsList.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(getSelectionListAction());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(pointsList);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
    }

    private ListSelectionListener getSelectionListAction() {
        return new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    extra.setSelectedPoint(pointsList.getSelectedValue());
                    extra.repaintCanvas();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void updateList() {
        listModel.removeAllElements();
        for (Map.Entry<Point, Boolean> currentPoint : extra.getPoints().entrySet()) {
            listModel.addElement(currentPoint.getKey());
        }
    }

    private ListCellRenderer<Point> getRender() {
        return new ListCellRenderer<Point>() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends Point> list, Point value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                JLabel cell = new JLabel("(" + value.x + " , " + value.y + ")");
                cell.setForeground(Color.black);
                return cell;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i can't just override Point's toString().

You need to use a custom renderer. Read the [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) section from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Lists`.